# How to load new data of a component after updating it from another component, in Reactjs

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I have an Event Model. in my event, people can indicate that they are attending an event by clicking a button, and when they indicate that they are attending an event by clicking a button, a Modal dialog will pop up from a different component to ask them if they also want to bring friends along to the event, if they say Yes, it will ask them to choose how many people they want to bring and they will choose from a drop-down list of numbers and submit. after submitting everything it will plus people that are coming and how many people the person is coming with then show them together. the Event model has going and coming_with attributes that keep the data of people that are coming and people that are coming along.

Note: the modal dialog is from another component that I am requiring inside my Event component.

the problem that I am facing now is that my view only updates the people that are coming but doesn't update the number of the people the person is bringing along unless I refresh the page. this was working when I was using class-based-component but after changing my code to function based component it stopped working.

How do I make the browser to update it automatically without refreshing the page?

Here is my Sandbox Link, https://codesandbox.io/s/compassionate-sanne-pmmx6?file=/event-comments.component.js

I think you will understand what I am saying after you visit the site

Comment: You're using `document.querySelector` to change rendered component?? You should really read some docs on how to use React properly.

Comment: Yes, I am less than two months with reactjs, I am new, and i only learn it on my free time, I did it that way but will definitely change as I learn more about react @marzelin

Answer (score 0):

Integrate `Redux` store in your React Application.

**SOLUTION: 1**

Get event data from the `API` and then store it in the reducer. Use that reducer to show data on your main screen.

After the modal appears, whatever data you select and posting it on `api`, update your reducer locally as well. Since that reducer will be linked to the main page, data will be `Updated`.

**SOLUTION: 2**

Introduce some variable in the reducer lets say `isUpdate`, make it true on updating data from `Modal`.
and in you main event page, use the Hook as follows to fetch data from api again and hence updated data will be shown.

```
useEffect(() => {
 if(isUpdate) 
 // fetchDataFromAPI
},[])
```

Comment: I never used Redux before, I am new to React and I only learn it in my free time. I will read up on it and see if I will be able to implement the example that you gave @Awais

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, everyone, but i hav solved this problem by events to after the API call. i saw the example on React Facebook page.

```
const [events, setEventData] = useState([]);

 useEffect(() => {
axios
  .get(
    "https://cryptic-shelf-72177.herokuapp.com/events/" +
      props.match.params.id +
      "/eventcomments"
  )

  .then((response) => {
    setEventData(response.data);
  })

  .catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error);
  });
}, [events]);
```